how to update envirment object without redraw entire View in SwiftUI
I am learning swiftUI.
I have created a sample demo that contains 2 screens. first one is a splash screen and another is the login screen.
In the splash screen, I used a timer with an interval of 5 seconds. when the count reaches 0 I want to redirect to the login screen.
the problem is Login screen redirecting multiple times.
here is starting Point
struct RoutingDemo_SwiftUIApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var router = Router()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $router.navPath) {
                SpashScreen().navigationDestination(for: Router.Destination.self, destination: { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .dashboardView:
                        TempView()
                    case .login:
                        LoginView().navigationTitle("")
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                    }
                })
            }.environmentObject(router)
        }
    }
}

here is code of splash screen
struct SpashScreen: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
   
    var body: some View {
        TimerView(callBack: {
            router.navigate(to: .login)
        })
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    SpashScreen()
}

struct TimerView: View {
    @State private var countDown = 5
    
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var callBack: (() -> Void)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "provider_splash", withExtension: "gif") {
                KFAnimatedImage(url).scaledToFill().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if countDown > 0 {
                countDown -= 1
            } else {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                callBack()
            }
        }
    }
}

here is  code of LoginView
struct LoginView: View {
   
    var body: some View {
        Button("Login", action: {
           
        })
    }
}

here is code of router
final class Router: ObservableObject {
    
    public enum Destination: Codable, Hashable {
        case login
        case dashboardView
    }
    
    @Published var navPath = NavigationPath()
    
    func navigate(to destination: Destination) {
        navPath.append(destination)
    }
    
    func navigateBack() {
        navPath.removeLast()
    }
    
    func navigateToRoot() {
        navPath.removeLast(navPath.count)
    }
}

I have tried to seperate timer view code from envirment object because updating envirment object cases swiftUI redraw entire view.

Hi @bhavesh, is splash screen and login views needed in navpath?, reason?.

hi @Immanuel, as you can see in the code I haven't added a splashscreen in navPath. splash screen is the starting point of the app. Based on whether the user is logged in or not it will push either the dashboard or login screen.

Just remove the Router object and use multiple .navigationDestination for each type of thing you want to show.
Remove onReceive and use TimelineView for your counter.

may I know what's the problem with the router object?. as i am learning swiftUI I want to know the part of the code cases problem.

You posted the problem

This will help you learn how to describe navigation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(for:destination:) “ Add this view modifier to a view inside a NavigationStack to describe the view that the stack displays when presenting a particular kind of data.”

actually, I know navigation destionaton modifier inside navigation stack used to redirect view. but i want seperate my navigation logic from view thats's why i created router object. could you please describe in detail what part of router object cases problem and what's the reason behind it.

SwiftUI is designed to work with structs that describe what you want to show. There should be no objects. The problem with objects is inconsistencies like the one you are facing right now.
